# Implement interface with generic types

Tags: java, generics

I have the following interface:

```
interface Parcel <VolumeType, WeightType> {
    public VolumeType getVolume();
    public WeightType getWeight();
}
```

I want to define a class A which implements this Parcel such that the volume and weight returned from this class have type Double, and the following codes stand

```
Parcel<Double,Double> m = new A(1.0,2.0);
m.getVolume().toString()+m.getWeight().toString().equals("1.02.0");
```

I am new to generics and all my trials for the definition of A failed. Can someone please show me an example about how to define such a class?

I have tried the following:

```
class A implements Parcel<Double, Double> {}
```

The error was

```
Constructor A in class A cannot be applied to given types;
        Parcel<Double,Double> m = new A(1.0,2.0);
                                  ^
  required: no arguments
  found: double,double
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
2 errors
```

Comment: Your class will need a couple of fields, a constructor that sets them, and the two getter methods declared in the interface.  Show us your best attempt, and we'll correct any errors.

Answer (score 1):

You've added the correct `implements` clause. The error you're getting is that you have not defined a two-argument constructor:

```
class A implements Parcel<Double, Double> {
    public A(double volume, double weight) {
        ...
    }
```

You'll also need to implement the two interface methods:

```
    public Double getVolume() {
        ...
    }

    public Double getWeight() {
        ...
    }
}
```